# Standard solution for SQL Views in Rails3 and Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-rds

I am looking for standard solution how to implement SQL views into the Rails3 project by using migrations and if somebody have experience with this topic based on Amazon RDS with MySql database. Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I solved this problem through [schema_plus](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus) gem which has a method create_view. And I have had not any issues with 'rake db:migrate' on Amazone RDS. So far so good. Hope this answer will be usefull for somebody. :)